# Crystal report suddenly printing Details section Twice

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I had made a vb.net application a year ago it was working fine till  few days back. But suddenly now after one-year Detail section started printing twice.

> Application created using Visual Studio 2013
>
> Crystal report version was 13.0.200
>
> Dot Net framework for application is 3.5

Searched online didn't find much info

Also updated the crystal report to SP25 but no luck!

After updating to SP25 it asked me to rebuild the project, so rebuild it but was giving me this error :

```
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So changed Dot net framework version of the application from **3.5 to 4.0**

Could anyone please help as troubleshooting from few days but couldn't find anything.

No change in Datasource or query was made.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: anything related to data entry change?

Comment: On the menu toolbar go to Database > Show SQL Query.  Copy the entire SQL statement shown here, then paste it into a Query Analyzer tool connected to your database.  Check the results of the SQL query for signs of duplication of the data.  When a detail section repeats itself, its usually due to duplication of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that the original problem is due to code. It is more likely due to database table joins.

Look at the table joins and try to identify what what record is now joining to 2 records instead of 1.

For example, do you have a single-record table to look up company info (e.g. logo)? If so, make sure that table doesn't have 2 records instead of 1.

Comment: yup! I just was going through my database and found there was a duplicate entry with same id. as it was just a table for converting numbers into words I didn't put primary key. So some how it created a duplicate entry with same record. and hence after that it was printing new rows as duplicate in crystal report. Thanks! for help.